# maximal irreducble subgroups of $SL(2,q)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

If $H$ is a maximal **solvable** irreducible subgroup of $GL(2,q)$ then intersection $H \cap SL(2,q)$ is maximal **solvable** irreducible subgroup of $SL(2,q)$. Why is it true?

Maybe this is not true, but is there any counterexample? (I cannot comment.)

Comment: Why do you think that is true? (It's not.)

Comment: It is true for maximal reducible subgroups.

Comment: Please answer my question. Why do you believe that this is true?

Comment: I believe this is false for $q=7$ and $9$, but true otherwise. The subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2,q)$ are all `known', so it's just a matter of checking the lists. If you have the ATLAS of finite simple groups, then you can check $q=7$ and $9$, where there are so-called novelty subgroups.

Comment: @user152903: You appear to have created two accounts, one of which is unregistered. You can request that these accounts be merged by [following these instruction](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) as best you can.